# how can I create user assigned identity and system assign identity with arm template on a app service

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity

Is it possible to assign both userAssigned identity and system assigned identity to app service with ARM template. if so, how can it be done.

Answer (score 1):

5 seconds in google:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "name": "[variables('appName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('appName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "hostingEnvironment": "",
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "alwaysOn": true
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "name": "[variables('appName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName'))]": {}
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('appName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "hostingEnvironment": "",
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "alwaysOn": true
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName'))]"
    ]
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity

ps. if you are asking to have both at the same time - its not possible

Comment: I want to add both to an app service at the same time

Comment: I think you can either have a system assigned OR user assigned. I am curious why one want both?

Comment: @Vikrant This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identity-best-practice-recommendations#multiple-managed-identities) describes one such use-case...

Answer (score 0):

As of **june 2023**, assigning *to the same Azure resource* both a system assigned and one or several user-assigned identities [look to be supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identity-best-practice-recommendations#multiple-managed-identities).

> Resources that support managed identities can have both a
> system-assigned identity and one or more user-assigned identities.

ARM Samples are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=arm%2Chttp).